# Bringing dialog window in from of Python window

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, tk-toolkit

My application has two separate dialog windows prior to opening the main application window. I am unable to figure out how to get the second dialog window (the calendar) to open in from of the black python screen (I apologize for my ignorance I don't know the name).

The messagebox contained in "rundate" opens first. If "no" is selected then the app_window opens. It is the app_window that gets hidden

```
conn = pyodbc.connect('Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};Dbq='+db)
cur = conn.cursor()

app_window = tk.Tk()
app_window.geometry("1x1+0+0")     
app_window.overrideredirect(True)  
app_window.transient()    


def rundate():
    result = tkinter.messagebox.askyesno(title="Rundate", message="back 7 days?")
    if result == True:
        end = date.today()
        start = date.today() - timedelta(7)
        daterange = [pd.date_range(start, end)]
        for single_date in daterange:
            x = single_date.strftime("%m/%d/%Y")
        rundate = x
        print(rundate)
        return rundate
    else:
        app_window.wm_title("Pick1")
        app_window.geometry("250x150+100+100")
    app_window.overrideredirect(False)
    #app_window.mainloop()
    cm = pick1.CalendarFrame(app_window)
    cm.grid()
    app_window.wait_variable(cm.wait_for_result)
    return cm.rundate

 rundate = rundate()
 print(rundate)
```

Then a whole bunch of code for queries and whatnot then

After the messagebox is returned "yes" OR the dates are selected from the calendar then the interface gets initiated

```
# Initiate interface    

root = Tk() 
master = Frame(root, name='master') 
master.pack(fill=BOTH) 
root.geometry("800x800+300+100")
root.title('WeeklyReport')

menu_bar = Menu(root)

def exit():
root.destroy()

root.wait_window
```

Comment: Please try to create a [mcve]. It's hard to diagnose with just some disjointed snippets. Though, one thing that looks suspect is that you're creating more than one instance of `Tk` which is generally now how tkinter is designed to be used.

Comment: Im sorry I will improve it but it is a VERY long script to I left out the gory details. The app_window is the new addition to the code so I think you are correct the there are too many instances of Tk

Comment: We don't need your whole script. We need a small program specifically written for this question.

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured it out by adding "lift" Thank you!

```
app_window = tk.Tk()
app_window.geometry("1x1+0+0")  
app_window.overrideredirect(True)  
app_window.transient()    

app_window.lift()
```